# Asp.net sorting repeater columns

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have a basic repeater on my aspx page with sort that uses viewstate in the code behind. Now this works perfectly fine but then my page starts loading really slow due to the huge viewstate it creates, along with web controls link buttons that are also very heavyweight.

A code sample:

```
protected void SortButtonCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    var curSort = Convert.ToString(ViewState[SortHelper.SortViewstateFieldKey]);
    var curDir = Convert.ToString(ViewState[SortHelper.SortViewstateDirKey]);
    var selSort = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
    ViewState[SortHelper.SortViewstateFieldKey] = selSort;
    BindRepeater();
}

private void BindRepeater() {
    // some code
    if(ViewState[SortHelper.SortViewstateFieldKey] != null) {
        var curSort = Convert.ToString(ViewState[SortHelper.SortViewstateFieldKey]);
        var curDir = Convert.ToString(ViewState[SortHelper.SortVieewstateDirKey]);
        switch(curSort) {
            case "ID":
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(curDir) || curDir.Equals(SortHelper.SortDirAsc)) {
                    data = data.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToList();
                }else {
                    data = data.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).ToList();
                }
                break;
            // more sorting based on the curSort value
        }
    }
}
```

front end code:

```
<cms:BasicRepeater runat="server" ID="rptData" OnItemCommand="RptDataItemCommand" ItemType="WebService call">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnId" runat="server" OnCommand="SortButtonCommand" CommandArgument="ID" Text="ID" /></th>
                // more th's
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
//// closing tags
```

So, now this all works. BUT is there any way I can possibly remove the use of viewstate and maybe a repeater all together and maybe use AJAX to populate an HTML table and do sorting without the use of webcontrols to reduce the viewstate so my page will load faster? If AJAX is possible are you guys able to point me in the right direction to get all this started?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Have a look at: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ for client-side sorting. The repeater you are using is not a native repeater. It may have an option to turn off ViewState. A standard repeater may be a little lighter anyway.

Comment: @JonP Unfortunately I can't use a jquery plugin are there any other alternatives to sorting that doesn't use a viewstate?

Comment: There are plenty of regular javascript options. I've only ever used the one I linked to but if you google "Javascript tablesorter" I'm sure you'll find a  few alternatives.